# Ubuntu starts with 2nd installed text entry language

Tags: 16.04, language-support, system-settings

As the title says, I have 2 languages installed in the Text Entry settings:
1. English
2. Russian

Whenever I start Ubuntu the active language is Russian even though it's the second one on the list.

Can this be fixed somehow?

[Text Entry Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLrVv.png)

Comment: That list does not determine which input source is active when you log in. The active input source when you log out does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last text entry language that you used before you logged out, restarted or shutdown is the text entry language that will be selected on the login screen the next time you login. You can also change the text entry language from the login screen. In fact you may need to change the text entry language at the login screen so that you can type your user password correctly. After you log in the text entry language will be the same as the text entry language that was selected at the login screen.

Comment: Any way to make Ubuntu switch to a specific language on start instead of the last one?

Comment: No, it always starts with the last text entry language. If that's not the right text entry language, you must change it manually at the login screen.